# Explore local geth node with web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I've just been trying to run the `web3.eth.getBlock` request as a test.

If I set my web3 provider to `https://api.myetherapi.com/eth` then the call is successful and returns the information about the block. However myetherapi has request limits so I figured I'd install geth and run my own node for this.

I installed geth and let it synch. Changed my web3 provider tocalhost http://localhost:8545 and I just get the following:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "".

myetherapi set provider:

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth'));
```

local provider:

```
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

Am I missing something key here? Thank you for the help.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
//not working provider.  returns the above error
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


//this provider works but it is myetherapi with api limits.  
//web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth'));
web3.eth.getBlock(5099447);
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you probably didn't start `geth` with the right command-line parameters. Try `geth --rpc --rpcapi="eth,web3,personal"`.

Comment: I believe this was the issue.  When I restarted geth with the command you posted and tried my program again it returned the information about the block without issue.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The below resolved my issue.

Posted by smarx:  Just a guess, but you probably didn't start geth with the right command-line parameters. Try geth --rpc --rpcapi="eth,web3,personal"